# Can't push anything with Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify

I am unable to make any changes to my Amplify project. If for example I edit the `index.py` file in my Amplify function, even if I just add a comment (so any change at all) and then attempt to push with `amplify push` I get:

```
 The following resources failed to deploy:
Resource Name: GraphQLAPITransformerSchemaXXXXX(AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema)
Event Type: update
Reason: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: XXXXXXX; S3 Extended Request ID: 2rDeCSlbgG0v0londkF....yidRAdAcAXB+iuZ4TN89T6x93vSb3IxCIk=; Proxy: null)
URL: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2#/stacks/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-west-2%3A824704040214%3Astack%2Famplify-learning-staging-136597-apiLearning-WDK....0ab0/events


 Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
Name: GraphQLAPITransformerSchema3CB2AE18 (AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema), Event Type: update, Reason: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: Q8TRKEQ4EF0B6GS4; S3 Extended Request ID: dBc...Hk=; Proxy: null)
```

How do I fix this? How do I stop it from happening again!

Comment: Here I am way outside Amplify *again* in the bowels of AWS with something that Amplify itself broke and provides no way to fix! Again our project has ground to a halt thanks to Amplify's bugs.

Comment: What specific change did you make?

Comment: @Luke It seems not to matter. In one test case, a single comment in a function.

Comment: So you pulled the backend, and tried pushing it without failure?

Comment: @Luke No: I can pull (even to a clean directory) and then push and it fails. Occasionally (though not always) a pull will restore a long deleted component (e.g. a function that had been absent for several pulls.

Comment: I'd suggest pulling your aws amplify project into a new blank folder, and start by making the changes little by little until you find what is causing your error.

Comment: @Luke Amplify is causing the error. That's the problem. I do that and push fails.

Comment: What state is your CloudFormation root stack in?

Comment: If you're really stuck, pay for AWS Developer Support and submit a technical ticket.

Comment: @Luke I've been waiting on my ticket since posting here ...